# How to save a picture to a relative file path in Jython

Tags: jython, jes

I'm trying to save an image file in the directory I'm running a JES program from, and it returns

```
The error was:java.lang.NullPointerException
I wasn't able to do what you wanted.
The error java.lang.NullPointerException has occured
```

my code is extremely simple,

```
map=makePicture(pickAFile())

writePictureTo(map,r'testfile.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMediaFolder()` to browse to the JES directory first.

Just an FYI, you can't save to a networked location using JES (as you can find in schools and universities)

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same boat as you before. Then I worked out that you need to put the correct path with a new image. 
Try to change the path like this:

```
writePictureTo(picture,"C://Users//Toshiba//Desktop//bulleyes.png")
```

You may put your computer name, and don't forget to use forward slash instead of backslash.

Comment: He was asking for saving to a relative path. You answer does not cover that.